# JAXB: unmarshal diferent xml to same object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have 3 input XML that have, pretty much, the same elements and attributes, in fact, they represent the same thing, so I want to marshall them to the same object, something like this:

Request One:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RequestOne>
    <id>123</id>
    <name>foo</name>
</RequestOne>
```

Request Two:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RequestTwo>
    <id>123</id>
    <value>val</value>
</RequestTwo>
```

Request Three:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RequestThree>
    <name>foo</name>
    <value>val</value>
</RequestThree>
```

Desired Object (something like):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Resource{

    @XmlElement
    private String id;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String value;

    //(...) more code
}
```

But I can't use multiple RootElement annotations to ask JAXB to unmarshall all of the 3 request to objects of the class `Resource`

Is there a way to do it? Or I must make the 3 sepparated classes?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Option 1***

Unmarshal using the overloaded Generic `unmarshal` method :

```
public static class Base {
    private String name ;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Base setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}

public static void main (String [] args) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Base.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<Base> basea = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<RootA><name>nanana</name></RootA>")), Base.class);
    System.out.println(basea.getValue().getName());
    JAXBElement<Base> baseb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<RootB><name>nbnbnb</name></RootB>")), Base.class);
    System.out.println(baseb.getValue().getName());
}
```

***Option 2***

You can always use Java's class subtyping capabilites ? JAXB does annotation scanning on parent class as well. This example works

```
public static class Base {
    private String name ;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Base setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement( name = "RootA")
public static class RootA extends Base{ 
}

@XmlRootElement( name = "RootB")
public static class RootB extends Base {
}


public static void main (String [] args) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootA.class,RootB.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    RootA rootA = (RootA)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader("<RootA><name>nanana</name></RootA>"));
    System.out.println(rootA.getName());
    RootB rootB = (RootB)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader("<RootB><name>nbnbnb</name></RootB>"));
    System.out.println(rootB.getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i used the first option and worked perfectly :D